# Why does specifying a particular column in select query making the sql query so much slower

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Why does including and renaming this column,`'feedback_panels.name as Location'` , in the select portion of the query increase load time from < 5 seconds to 20-30 seconds?

What can i do to speed up this query?

Query

```
        $data = FeedbackCard::select(DB::raw('feedback_cards.created_at as "Date Time"'),
            'users.name as User', 'feedback_panels.name as Location', 'location_feedbackpanels.location_tier_1_id',
            'location_feedbackpanels.location_tier_2_id', 'location_feedbackpanels.location_tier_3_id')
            ->join('feedback_panels','feedback_panels.id','=','feedback_cards.feedback_panel_id')
            ->join('users','users.id','=','feedback_cards.user_id')
            ->join('location_feedbackpanels','location_feedbackpanels.feedback_panel_id','=','feedback_panels.id')
            ->where('feedback_panels.client_id','=',$client_id)
            ->whereBetween('feedback_cards.created_at', [$start_date, $end_date])
            ->orderBy('feedback_cards.created_at','desc')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Just to be clear you only added the column to the select , the join to  feedback panels existed prior to this slowdown?

Comment: @P.Salmon yes, for some reason it slows down when I specifically select this column and rename it. Weirdly enough, feedback_panels.* doesnt slow the query .

Comment: Please show us the actual query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: Manually joining tables defeats the idea of using Eloquent, which is able to represent relations.

Answer (score 2):

`feedback_panels` probably would benefit from `INDEX(client_id, created_at)`

**Explanation**

That is a "composite" INDEX, meaning that there are multiple columns.

Think of it this way.  Suppose you are looking for `WHERE last = 'James' AND first = 'Rick':

With just `INDEX(last)`, you would need to rummage through all the Jameses checking each one for first=Rick.  But with `INDEX(last, first)`, you can zoom directly to (James, Rick).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @Roman - See if my Explanation helps.